# ORACLE: How to split sentences into 2 rows in spaces

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this problem where I have to split sentences if they are longer than 10 characters, but I can't break in the middle of the word, only between the words at the spaces.

For example, I have the sentence:

`dog jumps over lazy fox` = 23 characters

I have to make it into:

```
dog jumps 
over lazy
fox
```

Each row length must be <10 characters.

Comment: What actual output do you expect here?

Comment: sorry, edited the question @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: A database is a relatively lousy place to do this work.  I would much rather do this in Java, and then import the data into your database.

Comment: What about cases where the word itself is longer than 10 characters? Or punctuation at the end of a long word?

Answer (score 1):

If the question was in how to convert string by adding line break symbol, like word wrap where 10 is a line length. I suggest to use regexp like below:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('dog jumps over lazy fox', '(.{0,10})\s', '\1'||CHR(10),1, 0) FROM dual;
```

`'(.{0,10})\s'` - search statement finds any symbol from 0 to 10 (line length) where the next symbol is a non-word symbol.

`'\1'||CHR(10)` - replace found non-word symbol by line break chr(10)

Comment: if he need a result as collection of varchar(10), this answer will not work

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server try this:

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(50)='dog jumps over lazy fox',
@b varchar(50)

WHILE (len(@Text) > 0)
    BEGIN
        set @b = left((@Text), 10) 
        SELECT @b
        set @Text = stuff(@Text, 1, 10, '')
    END
```

Comment: thankyou but im having a hard time changing the idea into plsql

Comment: I just used sql to oracle converter :

     v_Text varchar2(50):='dog jumps over lazy fox';
            v_b varchar2(50)

        WHILE (length(rtrim(v_Text))>0)
        LOOP
        v_b:= substr((v_Text), 1,10) 
        SELECT v_b
        set FROM dual v_Text= stuff(v_Text,1,10,'')
        end loop

I hope this code will work on oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If convertion from string into table needed the implementantion is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE str_tbl_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_str_into_table(
  a_str IN VARCHAR,
  a_max_length IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10,
  a_pos NUMBER DEFAULT 1 ) RETURN str_tbl_typ
AS
 l_str VARCHAR(4000); 
 l_search_str VARCHAR(4000);
 l_pos NUMBER;
 l_str_length NUMBER;
 l_result str_tbl_typ;
BEGIN
  l_result := str_tbl_typ(); 
  l_search_str := a_str||' ';
  l_pos := a_pos;
  l_str_length := LENGTH(l_search_str) ;
  WHILE l_pos < l_str_length LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(l_str_length - FLOOR(l_pos/a_max_length)*a_max_length);
    IF l_str_length - FLOOR(l_pos/a_max_length)*a_max_length < a_max_length THEN
        l_str := SUBSTR(a_str, l_pos, l_str_length);
    ELSE
     l_str := REGEXP_SUBSTR( l_search_str, '(.{0,'||a_max_length||'})\s', l_pos, 1);
    END IF;
     l_result.extend;
     l_result(l_result.count) := l_str;
     l_pos := l_pos+length(l_str);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_result;
END convert_str_into_table;
/

SELECT * FROM TABLE(convert_str_into_table('dog jumps over lazy fox', 11));
```